# How to get percentage after grouping?

Tags: mysql, hadoop

I have a table like this:

```
person_id food   data
1         bread   xxx
1         bread   xxx
1         fruite  xxx
2         bread   xxx
2         fruite xxx
```

food can have only three values (bread, fruits), I want to get the percentage of bread each person has eaten, and there percentage of fruits each person has eaten.

I tried to do:

```
select count(*) from table
group by person_id, food
```

and that gives me:

```
player_id, food, number
```

but how can I continue from now?

I am on hadoop

Answer (score 0):

select person, t1.food, COUNT(*) total, COUNT(*) *100 / fcnt "Perc %"
from food_table t1, (select food, COUNT(*) fcnt from food_table group by food) testsum
where t1.food = testsum.food
group by t1.person, t1.food, fcnt
order by 1

Output
person  food    total   Perc % of total
1       bread   2       66
1      fruit    1       50
2      bread    1       33
2      fruit    1       50
[image: Output for Query]